# How can I set up eclipse che without TLS?

Tags: eclipse-che

All of the instructions for setting up eclipse che require setting up TLS and a cert manager for the k8s cluster.  I don't actually want TLS set up this way.  I want to have my AWS Load Balancer provide the certificates for TLS, and make that the only way in or out of the cluster.  I actually don't have a choice in this, as our IT will not provide us the certificate they want us to use any other way.

Comment: Setting up Eclipse Che without TLS is not recommend since some components (like Theia WebView) might not work properly.

Comment: @tolusha, could you clarify why some of these components might not work?